# Spring cloud feign behavior when parameter is empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am writing a feign client

```
@RequestMapping(
      path = "/TrackingServlet?CompanyName=Test&UserName=&BranchCode=",
      method = RequestMethod.GET,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
      )
  ResponseEntity<String> getInfo(
      @RequestParam("DocumentNumbers") String bill);
```

when it is invoked the url becomes `/TrackingServlet?CompanyName=Test&UserName&BranchCode`
eliminating the `=` symbol, but the API needs it in that format, since its a third party API we cannot modify it.

Also tried

```
@RequestMapping(
      path = "/TrackingServlet?CompanyName=Test&UserName=",
      method = RequestMethod.GET,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
      )
  ResponseEntity<String> getInfo(
      @RequestParam("DocumentNumbers") String bill,
      @RequestParam(name = "BranchCode", required = true) String BranchCode);

  default ResponseEntity<String> getInfo(String bill) {
    return getInfo(bill, "");
  }
```

this will not even have the param `BranchCode`

I am using `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:2.1.1.RELEASE`
Spring boot version 2.1.4.RELEASE

is there anyway or workarounds for keeping empty params in urls as it is ?

Comment: What is the API you are trying to access and what parameter you want to send as a `@RequestParam` ?

Comment: I want to hit `/TrackingServlet?CompanyName=Test&UserName=&BranchCode=&DocumentNumbers=12345`

Comment: I'd not put them in `path` but maybe try using a request interceptor or do as mentioned above and add them all as request parameters.

Comment: @spencergibb we tried adding in path and as request params, in both cases the `=` symbol is not there, even when we used newer versions. 
Now we are using spring request template, and it works fine with empty params in url, `=` symbol is not eliminated

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me

Answer (score -2):

If your URL is `http://localhost:8080/trackingServlet/testing?userName=pratik` 
Use feign client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "tracking-servlet-service")
public interface TestFeignClient {

        @GetMapping("/trackingServlet/testing")
        public String getQueryParam(@RequestParam("userName") String name);

}
```

If you have 2 or more parameter then you can add same in `@RequestParam`

E.g
URL `http://localhost:8080/trackingServlet/testing?userName=pratik&companyName=Test`

```
 @FeignClient(name = "tracking-servlet-service")
    public interface TestFeignClient {

            @GetMapping("/trackingServlet/testing")
            public String getQueryParam(@RequestParam("userName") String name, 
                                        @RequestParam("companyName") String companyName);

    }
```